# How to align words in pgfplots legend, is there a horizontal \smash?

Tags: pgfplots, alignment

In this legend, I'd like the second words ("measured", "measured", "regression", "regression") to line up, such that all four start at the same horizontal position. How to accomplish that?

[image]

If there was a horizontal `\smash` command, I'd try to solve it by changing e.g. the first legend entry to `\hphantom{\textsc{qt}}\hsmash{\textsc{pt}}, measured`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    legend entries={
    {\textsc{pt}, measured},
    {\textsc{qt}, measured},
    {\textsc{pt}, regression},
    {\textsc{qt}, regression}
    },
    legend cell align={left},
  ]
  \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2}; \addplot {x^3}; \addplot {x^4};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `\llap` and `\rlap`?

Comment: @Mico I hadn't heard of them. It seems they do exactly what I wanted `hsmash` to do?

Comment: An other way would be to add an extra column in the legend, but it would probably not be worth it as you would need extra `\addlegendimage{empty legend}` and adjustments of the column spacing.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Clever, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `\makebox` to ensure that all your `pt` and `qt` have the same width:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\textsc{qt},}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    legend entries={
    {\makebox[\mylen][l]{\textsc{pt},} measured},
    {\makebox[\mylen][l]{\textsc{qt},} measured},
    {\makebox[\mylen][l]{\textsc{pt},} regression},
    {\makebox[\mylen][l]{\textsc{qt},} regression}
    },
    legend cell align={left},
  ]
  \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2}; \addplot {x^3}; \addplot {x^4};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]